# Twitter user_email Request

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, twitter-oauth

Im using sign in Twitter in my iOS Project.. Ive done all the things need to setup. but i cant get user_email. I already checked the "Request Email to user" on twitter App. But still i got error.

Here's the error message

```
Request failed: unauthorized (401)
```

And Heres may code

```
TWTRAPIClient *client = [TWTRAPIClient clientWithCurrentUser];
            [client requestEmailForCurrentUser:^(NSString *email, NSError *error) {
                if (email) {
                    NSLog(@"signed in as %@", email);
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                }

            }];
```

I hope you can help me on this. Thanks!

Comment: check your auth key and secret. There is something wrong with them..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. TWTRAPIClient had two TWTRSession in session store. Reinstall app. This will fix the problem.